# Angular2 (front) and Yii2 (end) - http.get with option 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Tags: json, xml, angular, yii2

I'va been trying to connect Angular2 sample "Tour of Heroes" as frontend part and Yii2  framework as backend
controller in yii2

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
class HeroesController extends ActiveController
{

    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Heroes';

    public function behaviors()
    {

        return       
        yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
            'corsFilter' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Result (http://server.local/heroes):

```
<response>
<item>
<id>11</id>
<name>Mr. Nice</name>
<title>князь</title>
</item>
<item>
<id>12</id>
<name>Narco</name>
<title>граф</title>
</item>
<item>
<id>13</id>
<name>Bombasto</name>
<title>барон</title>
</item>
```

curl H 'Content-Type': 'application/json' 'http://server.local/heroes' is working quite correctly and I get JSON

But I can't receive this in Angular2. http.get with options Content-Type': 'application/json

```
export class HeroService {
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers});
  private heroesUrl ='http://server.local/heroes';// 'app/heroes';  // URL     to web api
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
               return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl, this.options      
    )
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

But I get an empty Hero[]

Comment: any shown error in your browser's console ? could you also check if the request has been properly sent from the dev tool's network tab ?

Comment: no errors in Chrome console

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [Yii Response Formatting](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-response-formatting.html) or using this in your controller

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();


        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            ],

        ];
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```